# Allow user to login from one device at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I have been searching Google to find a answer to if it is possible to restrict users to login from one device at a time.

Suppose there is a web application (Ruby on Rails application) which allows one user to login from one device at a time.  How can this be achieved ?

To solve this problem, I think the first thing is to identify a device. Maybe by its Mac address, but I did not find any way to fetch the Mac address of a device from user request made from a browser.

I also considered `request.remote_ip` but that can be same for multiple devices connected to one Wi-Fi.

It would be really helpful if anyone could share some thoughts about possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: What's desired application behavior from UI perspective? For example, there is a user connected from device A, and the same account is going to used to login from device B. Will user from A be disconnected? Or login from B be declined?

Comment: Login from B should be declined.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on `request.remote_ip` either. Because of NAT a single ip address can be shared to multiple users and/or devices, for example - common case is home router or cellular data.

But you can generate an unique session id/token on user login and store it both in cookies and on server side and then check for it. When user logs in from second device - this will overwrite the former token and the latter session will become the only one allowed to user. Or you can deny the second login when previous session exists (was not terminated or timed out) depending on your logic.

For `devise` gem there's `devise-security` gem that provides `:session_limitable` strategy that implements rule for first session becoming unusable.

Comment: Thanks. This is a potential solution which I have considered. I want to log out the device which is trying to login if there is already an active session existing in the server. Also what if user opens an incognito tab and logs in from the same system or user opens another browser from the same system and tries to login ? Is it right to stop the user from login from the same device? There can be multiple active session from one device in this scenario.

Comment: @dp7 another non-incognito tab will not count as second login as cookies will be shared, but login from incognito or second will be counted as from another device, which seems pretty logical, because cannot be distinguished from actual second device on same net

Comment: exactly. That's been the challenge. If we stop a user to access his account from the same system using different browser or incognito mode, then it won't be a good experience for the user.

Answer (score 1):

My Personal Opinion, You do not need a specific unique id or something else.

> If user sign-in first time, generate JWT, UNIQ or etc. token and save
> it in DB.
>
> Now you know user signed in, cause the token field is taken.
>
> If user sign-out, kill the token and make empty the token field.
>
> From 2nd devise, attempting to sign in message it "You are already sign in with different devise. Please, SignOut from that blabla.."
>
> If doesn't have an access, then similar to password reset email to reset an account auth.

And based on token you can use stateless authentication also, keeping it in `localstorage` or `cookie`. This is extra logic board.

Comment: Suppose user opens an incognito mode in browser and logins to the application. As per your suggestion, it will create a token to indicate an active session. What if user closes the browser without Sign Out ? That means token would still be there in the backed data store. Then same user opens browser and tries to login again, then as per logic it won't allow the same user to login from the same system.

Comment: @dp7 That's why, you dnt have to use session based authentication, if wanna make restrictions. Just go for stateless authentication (JWT). I use personally JWT, and never rely on active session in auth, and requests.

Comment: Also, If we are talking about only mobile devices then `UDID` is perfect for it https://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/device-ID-device-identification .For browser is good `token` based for single device or browser restriction.

Comment: Not sure UDID is useful if the web app is accessible from browser without having any native iOS/Andrioid app. As you said, JWT looks promising. I will explore it and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure how this question can be solved with JWT approach.  If system A has the JWT token and successfully logged in, then how another login attempt can be declined when other login user would have a valid JWT token also ? If I opt for storing JWT token in cookie, then again it wont be shared between two different browsers running in one system.